# Laravel Authentication with "Remember me" strange behavior

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

Well, I have a simple login page, with a Remember me check box.

The problem is that same thing happens if I:
- check,
- uncheck,
- even use `Auth::attempt(array('email'=> $usr,'password'=> $psw))` w/o the second argument.

All the times the application remembers me!

the even more strange point is this:

```
    if (Auth::viaRemember())
    {
        echo "remembered! ";
    } else {
        echo "not remembered. "; // <-ALWAYS :(
    }
```

So Laravel every time says that she is not remembering me, but it acts the opposite way.

I'm on localhost if it makes any difference.

**Edit**

When I check "remember me" a cookie is set in addition to `laravel_session` called `remember_xxxxxxxxxxxx...`, but the script echos `not remembered` as I said, and it remembers me whether this cookie is set or not.

And it forgets me Only if I delete `laravel_session` manually.

Comment: I may be way off base, but is your config/session.php file setup correctly? Is it possible your session lifetime is too long?

Comment: Are you logging out? Remember me means that you keep your login for *longer*. But even without Remember me, the application will remember you for the length of your session.